# Does Cloudant support couch_httpd_oauth with use_users_db = true?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

Posted here by request, after asked on irc #cloudant

Does Cloudant support couch_httpd_oauth with use_users_db = true?  (This, of course, implies that I would have disabled Cloudant's security in favor of CouchDB native features.)

And if so, how can it be enabled on my database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudant doesn't yet support OAuth.  Behind CORS support it's probably our most requested feature.

Answer (score 2):

Try out [Smileupps](https://www.smileupps.com). It offers official CouchDB releases and features.. this means you can have couch_httpd_oauth support with use_users_db enabled.